# Getting the value from a Select tag (Grails)

Tags: sorting, grails, html-select

I'm having a problem getting the select tag to work for me in Grails. Basically, I am trying to get a value from the select field and use it to sort a list being displayed on the gsp. The select tag looks like this:

```
<g:select from="['Ascending','Descending']" name="selectTest" id="selectTest" />
```

I am trying to use g:links to pass the information on. I was hoping I could do something similar to

```
<g:link action="sort" id="pid" params="[direction:${selectTest.value}]">Sort</g:link>
```

However, this does not work as the value is always passed as null. I can pass the data I want using a form and an actionSubmit, but I have 3 different tables columns that I need to be able to sort, so determining the desired column would be a pain. Also, there is no domain object being used, so using g:sortableColumn tags doesn't work either.

Is there a way to do this without having to use JavaScript and hiddenFields?

Comment: Are the select and link both in the same gsp? These are both rendered on the server, so the selectTest value is not populated until the form is completed. The link tag will return null unless you populate in the controller before passing control to the view to render.

Comment: Yes, they are both in the same gsp. So you are saying I need to populate the select tag before passing control to the view?

Comment: Selection can be (and will be) changed on client side, so you have to use javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by me forgetting to wrap the select tags in a form tag. I wrapped them in a form submit tag and I can now access the information by using the select tags id and clicking on an actionSubmit button.